# Timer Interval change from combo box

Tags: c#, timer

I have items in a combo box. When I selected the item, the timer interval must be multiplied by the number selected in the combo box.
But when run the code it says "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Value '0' is not a valid value for Interval. Interval must be greater than 0."
the items in the combo box are 1,2,4,8,10 and 20.

the code is below

```
int x1;
        private int ch1xscale()
    {
        x1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmbch1.SelectedItem);
        return x1;

    }

timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick;
        timer1.Interval = 100*ch1xscale();
        

        cmbch1.SelectedIndex = 3;
```

what is wrong here ?

Comment: You are setting the interval before an item is selected?

Comment: @Deolus when the form loads, I have selected an index, "cmbch1.SelectedIndex = 3; and the interval is also set when the form loads.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an example. If you set your code according to this example, it will work without any problems. Just try to set the `interval` and do not change the other sample variables of the timer class.

Just because the timer is a thread I had to use a `delegate` to synchronize to use the other controls.

1.create timer

```
Timer timer;
public delegate void InvokeDelegate();
int x1;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Interval = 100;
    timer.Start();
}
private int ch1xscale()
{
    x1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmbch1.SelectedItem);
    return x1;
}
```

2.timer tick

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //do work
   this.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(InvokeMethod));
}
void InvokeMethod()
{
     myLabel.Text = timer.Interval.ToString();
}
```

3.combobox selected changed event

```
private void cmbTimer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Interval = 100 * ch1xscale();
    timer.Start();           
}
```

Comment: @meyasam asadi: It worked as in the given part 3. But I had to use Convert.ToInt32 instead of ToDouble as it an error occured "CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)". I faced the same problem even before this question is posted. How to include the double type variables here. My Interval type is milliseconds.

Comment: I used System.Timers.Timer whose Interval received a double value. I changed it according to your code. I modified the code. This is what you want now.